# Using the Quickbooks ruby gem how do I return invoices by customer_ref?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, quickbooks

I need to query invoices by customer_ref. I have tried:

```
invoices = service.query("Select * From Invoice Where customer_ref = 75")
```

But that just returns:

```
Quickbooks::IntuitRequestException: Error parsing query:
QueryParserError: Encountered " <INTEGER> "75 "" at line 1, column 44.
Was expecting one of:
"false" ...
"true" ...
```

How can I return invoices by customer_ref?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.. I am going to answer my own question with a link to help others if they stumble across similar problems. Check out the Advanced SQL Query page provided by Intuit:

https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2014/03/20/advanced-sql-queries

```
invoices = service.query("Select * From Invoice Where CustomerRef = '75'")
```